# Figuring out which JavaScript set a given CSS property

Tags: html, css, debugging

I am debugging a complex Front End HTML GUI and at some point some JavaScript adds a CSS property to an element, which shouldn't be there.

I am looking for a way to see which JavaScript code (in terms of file and line number) amended the given (in this case `style`) property so I can debug it further.

Since the JS code is enormous searching the code is not practical. I need some way to bind to property change events and see who changed them.

Comment: You have search that in resources from each JS file.

Comment: Website and / or source code?

Comment: @aavrug The file is several thousand lines of code long and is partially obfuscated. Searching the source is not practical.  I need some way to bind to property changes and see who changed them.

Comment: @ItayGrudev So go through each JS file and use ```ctrl+f```

Comment: @Caelan That is irrelevant since the question should be universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on html element in Chrome Devtools => Break on => Attributes Modifications. It make code to stop on a point when css property is changed by javascript. If it will stop inside library that changes the css than use the Sorces => Call Stack (at the right) of Devtools toget to the piece of code that calls the library to change css.

Comment: That's neat. Is there a way to save those between page reloads?

Comment: I can just add a break point in the beginning of my JS so I can add the attr break point before the JS is ran.